# Images stored on a HTTPS server, how to retrieve them?

Tags: java, android, https

Below is a sample code that I use to access a sample jpg file on , but after connection, I don't get to see the length of the file nor is the file downloaded on the sdcard!.(isn't accessign HTTP connection and HTTPS connetion same?)

Here is the sample code that I use. url = "https://calomel.org/calomel_footer.jpg"

```
private Bitmap getImageBitmap(String url) {
    Bitmap bm = null;
    try {
        URL aURL = new URL(url);
        URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();
        Log.i("My_App", "Content Type = "+URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(url));
        conn.connect();
        Log.i("My_App", "Content Length = "+conn.getContentLength());
        Log.i("My_App", "Content Type = "+conn.getContentType());
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("/mnt/sdcard/calomel_footer.jpg"));
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        byte buf[]=new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while((len=is.read(buf))>0) {
            fos.write(buf,0,len);
        }
        fos.close();
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
        bis.close();
        is.close();

   } catch (Exception e) {
       Log.e("My_App", "Error getting bitmap", e);
   }
   return bm;
}
```

and I get the lenght displayed as -1 and Content Type2 as null.

Also when I see my file stored under the "/mnt/sdcard/calomel_footer.jpg" I get to see 0 bytes file.

Can anyone help me with the solution?

Answer (score 0):

The null from `getContentType()` is because the webserver did not provide a suitable header. The -1 from `getContentLength()` is because again the webserver did not provide a suitable header and is sending it in chunk encoding.

In these circumstances the length is only discoverable by actually downloading the file and seeing how many bytes you got.

Comment: I get 0 bytes file when I download

Answer (score 0):

First off, the image at https://calomel.org/calomel_footer.jpg does not load for me. I see a message saying [The image “https://calomel.org/calomel_footer.jpg” cannot be displayed because it contains errors.].

Secondly, you are getting the input stream from the webserver, and you are writing that through the file output stream.
After that is done, you are attempting to read the same webserver input stream again (which you are doing through the BitmapFactory). These streams are only good once. What you want to do is something like:

```
while((len=is.read(buf))>0) {
        fos.write(buf,0,len);
    }
    fos.close();
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile); // myFile is the File that you wrote the FileOutputStream to.
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
    bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
```

Comment: I think my code does two parts, once part stores the file and the other part send the bitmap object. It does work on a http server... I mean it works perfectly fine for a HTTP connection.