# Unable to retrieve the image of https format for facebook in android?

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to get images from facebook using following method. I'm getting an error "SSL denied". I got the image urls from the facebook API. The image urls are of facebook profile pictures.

```
ImageView image=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.iView);

String imageurl=https://graph.facebook.com/100000685876576/picture;

Drawable drawable=LoadImageFromWebOperations(imageurl);

image.setImageDrawable(drawable); 

private Drawable LoadImageFromWebOperations(String url) {

    try {   
        InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
        return d;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //Log.e("DEMO ADAPTER",e.toString());
        return null;
    }
}
```

can anyone help me out...
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
public static Bitmap downloadfile(String fileurl)
    {
        Bitmap bmImg = null;
        URL myfileurl =null;
        try
        {
            myfileurl= new URL(fileurl);
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try
        {
            HttpURLConnection conn= 
                    (HttpURLConnection)myfileurl.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.connect();
            int length = conn.getContentLength();
            if(length>0)
            {
                int[] bitmapData =new int[length];
                byte[] bitmapData2 =new byte[length];
                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new 
                            BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inSampleSize = 1;

                bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is,null,options);

            }
            else
            {

            }

        } 
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bmImg;               
    }
```

Comment: @CapDroid::hi I tried but it is showing a blank page...As the url is https Is it necessary to do anything more??

Comment: ohh yes there are many question in statckoverflow so u can search and get right answer bcz i hv not any code for it..

Comment: I searched for it...http://mobile.synyx.de/2010/06/android-and-self-signed-ssl-certificates/....     http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#SSL_versions_1.2C_2.2C_and_3....    http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml.html#Secure_URLs....    but still i didnt get the right answer..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587788/images-stored-on-a-https-server-how-to-retrieve-them   i didnt get this...

Comment: hey i got it i just replaced the https with http in url with the above method given by CApDroid...

Comment: Yes it is working fine....I have a doubt.can we see the user profile of facebook with our application.

Comment: Tell me how to accept the answer in stackoverflow...i didnt get the option anywhere and i dnt know how to accept ur answer...